# Issue With Angular Routing

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I am trying to route from one component to another within the same module in angular but I am getting the below error after clicking on the 'Submit' Button - This is the action on which the component should switch.

**LoginComponent.ts**

```
login () {
    if (this.username === 'Iftekhar' && this.password === 'Sunny') {
      const user: User = {
        'id' :1 ,
        'name' :'Iftekhar'
      };
      this.store.dispatch ( new LoggedInAction ( {user} ) );
      this.route.navigateByUrl('courses');
    }
    const courses = [
      {
        'id' :1 ,
        'name' :'Course 1'
      }
    ];
    this.store.dispatch ( new LoadCourses ( {courses} ) );
    this.route.navigateByUrl('/courses').catch(err=>{
      console.log(err);
    })
  }
```

**AppRoutingModule.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'courses', component: CoursesComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
export const RoutingComponent =  [CoursesComponent]
```

**Error:-**

```
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'courses'
    at ApplyRedirects.push../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js.ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.js:2469)
    at CatchSubscriber.selector (router.js:2450)
    at CatchSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/catchError.js.CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:34)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:80)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:60)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:80)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:60)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:80)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:60)
    at TapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/tap.js.TapSubscriber._error (tap.js:61)
```

The Complete Code is available here - https://github.com/training-session-101/Angular6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this code:

```
this.route.navigateByUrl('courses');
```

Another problem is that you have imported wrong Routing Definition file which does not have any routes configured

```
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
```

it should be

```
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app.routing.module';
```

delete the extra file.

Comment: okie.. yes .. I tried after removing the '/' but still, it didn't work :(